# Installing on eMachine Netbook Problems

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, xubuntu, lubuntu

I have a netbook
(Specs:
Intel Atom N270 Processor,
1GB RAM,
160GB HDD)
And it was running Windows and was very slow. I wanted to format the drive and install a Linux distro like Lubuntu so I made a USB Boot Drive for Windows 10, allowing me to format the drive. Then I made a USB Boot Drive for Lubuntu and when I boot to the drive I get these errors:

```
ACPI Error: [CAPB] Namespace lookup failure, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20160930/dsfield-211)
ACPI ERROR: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCIO._OSC] (Node f5094ba0), AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20160930/psparse-543)
```

Then, the splash screen starts and loads for a little then leaves again, leaving me at a initramfs console with these errors above it:

```
usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 1-1: device not accepting address 4, error -71
usb 1-1: device not accepting address 5, error -71
usb usb1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 2-1: device not accepting address 4, error -71
usb 2-1: device not accepting address 5, error -71
usb usb2-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

These are my Rufus settings when I made the USB
[Rufus Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KZFs.png)

I've been unable to find a good help thread with someone who has a similar problem, if someone knows of a thread and could link me it, or just has a solution that would be wonderful. Thanks :)